Retained earnings in balance sheet, income statement and cashflow statement
Why don't the change in retained earnings in balance sheets match with the retained earnings calculated by Income statement and Statement of Cash Flows. Is there anything I am missing here?
Difference between retained earnings between year 2023 and 2022 is $80,890.
Retained earnings calculated from income statement and statement of cash flows (Net Income - Dividends) which is  $86,281.
Here is the link to 10-K filings https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/354707/000035470724000012/he-20231231.htm

On Page 95 you'll see the reconciliation of Retained Earnings:
Balance, December 31, 2022                    845,830
Net income for common stock                   199,238
Common stock dividends ($1.08 per share)     (118,348)      
Balance, December 31, 2023                    926,720   

For a difference of 80,890.  As to why the "dividends" listed on page 95 are different than the "dividends" listed on the Cash Flow Statement on page 97, you'll have to look through the notes and see if that's explained.
Note that there are other items that could affect Retained Earnings in that reconciliation; it's not always just Net Income - Dividends. That's just a general formula that does not account for every possible variable.
